# Angular CLI & Docker: ng serve change detection very slow

Tags: angular, docker

I have an Angular 5.2 app running in a Docker container, and for development purposes I am using Angular CLI's `ng-serve` to serve the app which provides auto-reloading on changes. My original working serve command;

`ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80 --disable-host-check`

This functions fine, and I can access the served app from the host machine as expected.

To the above, thanks to various sources, I added the `--poll 1000` flag, which tells the CLI to poll files for changes every 1000ms, without which it never detects changes, and thus never recompiles and updates. My issue here is that between a file being changed and the change being detected within the docker container triggering the rebuild, there is a delay of up to 15-20 seconds. I have confirmed that the file changes are translated into the container as I can `cat` the edited file immediately on save within the container and see the changes. I can change the poll timeout to 1ms and this does reduce the delay to a few seconds, but this obviously isn't ideal and the delay is still substantial.

Why would such a delay exist?

---

- **OSX version**: 10.11.6
- **Docker version**: Docker version 18.04.0-ce, build 3d479c0
- **Docker Machine**: 0.14.0, build 89b8332
- **Docker Compose**: 1.21.0

---

```
// docker-compose.yml
web-client:
  build:
    context: ../web-client/
    dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - ../web-client/:/var/www/web-client
  container_name: web-client



// Dockerfile
FROM node:9.11

COPY ./ /var/www/web-client

ENTRYPOINT ["/var/www/web-client/docker/entrypoint.sh"]



// entrypoint.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cd /var/www/web-client

yarn run start



// package.json
"scripts": {
    ...
    "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80 --poll 1 --disable-host-check",
    ...
}
```

Comment: How you did mounting at run time or docker file which command u used
? which OS you using? and docker version these thing need to be clear before answer this question

Comment: @Adiii I've added version numbers and what I believe are the relevant scripts

Comment: okay let me check with above setting

Answer (score 1):

Here is my setup that is fairly fast,

docker compose, exposes port 4200 to the outside, mounts src folder to detect changes:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    container_name: my-spa-dev
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.test
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/src/app/src
```

Dockerfile.test:

```
FROM node:10
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn install

COPY . .

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

run with `docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml up`